# $f(x)$, $g(x)$ polynomials with real coefficients. If $f(x)g(x) = f(x^2 + x + 1)$ then $f(x)$ is of even degree

Tags: polynomials

Let $f(x)$, $g(x)$ be polynomials with real coefficients. If $f(x)g(x) = f(x^2 + x + 1)$ for all $x$ belonging to $\mathbb{R}$, show that $f(x)$ is of even degree. How do I show that $f(x)$ is of an even degree. Does the statement even degree include the condition that the degree is zero?

Comment: Hint: Show that you cannot have $f(x) = 0$ for any (real) $x$. What happens if you assume $f(x) = 0$?

Comment: I'd like to see two nontrivial such polynomials.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $f(x)$ had odd degree, then it would have real roots. Let $x_0$ be the greatest real root. Then$$0=f(x_0)g(x_0)=f({x_0}^2+x_0+1).$$So, ${x_0}^2+x_0+1$ is another real root of $f(x)$, which is impossible, since ${x_0}^2+x_0+1>x_0$ and $x_0$ is the greatest real root.

Comment: Very nice! A pleasure to read.